# Calling same method for different integers

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to call the following method:

```
public void moveForward(int spaces) {
    if(spaces >= 0) {
        if(canvas.greenX == 0) {
            if(canvas.greenY == 0) {
                canvas.greenX = canvas.greenX + spaces;
            }
            else if((canvas.greenY - spaces) < 0) {
                int m = spaces - canvas.greenY;
                canvas.greenY = 0;
                canvas.greenX = canvas.greenX + m;
            }
            else {
                canvas.greenY = canvas.greenY - spaces;
            }
        }
    }
    canvas.repaint();
}
```

But I want to be able to change different values (i.e redX, redY, blueX, blueY, etc...) in my canvas object dependent on which colour needs to move forward.

I know that I could write out the method again, but instead use the different values, but I'm sure there's a way to just pass the values into the method itself.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: research `Strategy Pattern`

Comment: `greenX`, `greenY` are not a properties of the `Canvas` you need to show more relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Strategy Pattern:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

> Defines a family of algorithms, encapsulates each algorithm, and makes
> the algorithms interchangeable within that family.

Create instances of each `MoveStrategy` and add them to an [immutable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) `Map<Move,MoveStrategy>` and with the `Red`, `Green` and `Blue` enums as the keys to the map. Then you can easily select the logic you want to perform with a simple `.get(RED).move()` or `.get(GREEN).move()`

```
public enum Move { RED, GREEN, BLUE }

public interface MoveStrategy
{
    public void move(final int spaces);
}

public abstract class BaseMoveStrategy
{
    protected final Canvas canvas;

    protected BaseMoveStrategy(@Nonnull final Canvas canvas) { this.canvas = canvas; }
}

public class MoveRed extends BaseMoveStrategy implements MoveStrategy
{
    public MoveRed(@Nonnull final Canvas canvas) { super(canvas); }

    @Override public void move(final int spaces) { /* logic for Red goes here */ }
}

public class MoveBlue extends BaseMoveStrategy implements MoveStrategy
{
    public MoveBlue(@Nonnull final Canvas canvas) { super(canvas); }

    @Override public void move(final int spaces) { /* logic for Blue goes here */ }
}

public class MoveGreen extends BaseMoveStrategy implements MoveStrategy
{
    public MoveGreen(@Nonnull final Canvas canvas) { super(canvas); }

    @Override public void move(final int spaces) { /* logic for Green goes here */ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up using a far less elegant solution but this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to further decompose your types. You're saying in a comment that your values are `int`s. In that case, you can use the class `java.awt.Point` since it has attributes `int` x and y.

So in your class `Canvas` you replace greenX, greenY, redX, redY etc. with:

```
Point green;
Point red;
Point blue;
```

and in your method `moveForward`, you add the coloured point that you want to adjust as an argument:

```
public void moveForward(int spaces, Point coloredPoint) {
```

and inside the method you replace `canvas.greenX` with `coloredPoint.x`, `canvas.greenY` with `coloredPoint.y`.

Voila, problem solved!